# How to read XMLString coming from server side in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a XML string like this and I want to parse it a to javascript string but I am getting an error like this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` . I have tried different function and lastly I tried using this code :

Code:

```
   var XML_CHAR_MAP = {
            '<': '&lt;',
            '>': '&gt;',
            '&': '&amp;',
            '"': '&quot;',
            "'": '&apos;'
        };

        function escapeXml(s) {
            return s.replace(/[<>&"']/g, function (ch) {
                return XML_CHAR_MAP[ch];
            });
        }

        var content = escapeXml('@Model.XSLTContent');
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

                xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"

                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"

                xmlns:urn="urn:Magento"

                xmlns:dis="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS"

                xmlns:ebay="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"

                xmlns:sourcelib="lib:SourceAppResource"

                xmlns:destinationlib="lib:DestinationAppResource"

                xmlns:genericlib="lib:genericAppResource"

                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl dis env xsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <Envelopes>

      <!-- [rootXPath] need to define-->

      <!--<xsl:for-each select="//item">-->

      <xsl:for-each select="//product">

      <xsl:variable name="traceConflictBucket" select="genericlib:TraceConflictBucket(id)"/>

      <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

        <env:Header>

          <SessionID>{0}</SessionID>

        </env:Header>

        <env:Body>

          <dis:Add xmlns:dis="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS" >

            <BOM>

              <BO>

                <AdmInfo>

                  <Object>AECITEMLOG</Object>

                </AdmInfo>





              </BO>

            </BOM>

          </dis:Add>

        </env:Body>

      </env:Envelope>





      </xsl:for-each>

      <!--</xsl:for-each>-->

    </Envelopes>



  </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with the escaped string?  If it's output to the page, then just use `<pre>` - if it's use the data then parse with jquery.

Comment: Seems like a job for [jquery parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the job of  `parseXML` native parsing function of Jquery.  You may try `jQuery.parseXML(data)`. I have tried this one works fine for

```
var xml = "..........YOUR XML.........",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "...YOUR XML ATTRIBUTE...." );
alert($title.text());
```

You can take reference from [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Hope it helps you.